# Android activity reopen after start a new activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-manifest

I have a activity called MainActivity that calls a new activity (Tutorial):

```
Intent secondActivity = new Intent(this, Tutorial.class);
startActivity(secondActivity);
```

After calling the startActivity, the onCreate of MainActivity is open again. Why this happens? I migrated from Eclipse to Android Studio, and this issue did not happen on Eclipse.

@update1:

The MainActivity is first activity to open on my project. After that I call the TutorialActivity.

Manifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.teste.animationxml" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">


        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".Tutorial">
    </activity>

    <activity
    android:name=".Volume"
    android:label="app_second" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".Parabens"
        android:label="app_second" >
    </activity>

</application>
```

Regards

Best regards

Comment: You would need to provide more code and explanation than this for help. Does Tutorial never start and Main just starts? Does Tutorial open then Main opens on top of it? We don't know

Comment: The MainActivity is first activity to open on my project. After that I call the TutorialActivity.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But you didn't answer any of the questions

Comment: Sorry, the Tutorial opens on the top of Main. But i do not want the onCreate of Main is called again.

Comment: Show us your manifest

Comment: The onCreate() of main won't be called again when you open your second activity. Why do you say it is?

Comment: ok, i have just updated